# AnularJS $resource の取得値のresolveについて

Tags: angularjs

$resourceを利用して、JSONに記述した設定値を取得するとき、
非同期であるため、$resourceの戻り値が解決されません。
$resourceの$primiseにはresolveも無いので、どのように解決しますか？

```
myApp.factory('prop', function($resource) {
  return {
    getSetting: function(key) {
      var res = $resource('setting.json').query();
      return res.key;
    }
  }
});
```

---

非同期を同期にするのは難しそうなので、下記のようにしてkeyに対する値を非同期で返すことにしようと思います。

```
myApp.factory('prop', function($resource) {
  return {
    getSetting: function(key) {
      return $resource('setting.json').query().$promise.then(function(res) {
        return res[key];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

非同期で取得するのなら、上記のソースで言うと、query関数のコールバックまたはres.$promise.thenでJSONが取得されていることが確定するので、その中で処理するのはいかがでしょうか。

同期的に処理するのは少し難しいと思います。
[AngularJSのngResourceで同期処理](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8405/angularjs%E3%81%AEngresource%E3%81%A7%E5%90%8C%E6%9C%9F%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86)
こちらで質問させて頂いて一応同期的に処理するのは可能でしたが、少し仕掛けが必要でした。

Comment: 本家でも聞いてみましたが反応がありませんでした。非同期を同期にするのは難しそうですね。naga3さんが質問されていたように、代入で確定したかったのですが、難しそうなので、コールバック関数内で、keyに該当する値に絞り込んで、thenの戻り値にしてやろうと思います。
ありがとうございました。